# Java Splash Screen Application

Tags: java, ant, rmi

I am running into an issue where it takes a really long time (10 seconds or so) to get through my ANT setup and running my java application.  This will delay the splash screen for the jvm by at least 10 seconds to show up.  Unfortunately, I can not move away from ANT to start the application due to certain constraints.  What I would like to be able to do, and was wondering if anyone had a better solution, is to create a small splash screen application that would have the splash screen as an argument to the JVM so it will show up quickly and then use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript....) to launch the other application.  My concern is how to kill off the first application.

What I was thinking of doing is using jps within the other application to get the PID for the class that kicked off the application and then kill the Process (the first application would also have a timer to avoid it staying around if the second application did not start for some reason).  I should say that there is a constraint that the main application (the second application) can only be run once and I have a bind solution to avoid this.  I was wondering if there is a better way to terminate the first application.  Should I use RMI or another way to tell the application to exit?  If possible the less networking the better.

Comment: You really plan to deploy the application with ANT included? Why? Very strange requirement.

Comment: yes it is very odd.  I am also looking into if we can remove the ant requirement for what we were using it for and replace it in some way.  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first application (splash application) create a server socket with port XXX and listen for incoming messages, and apiece of code to terminate itself (e.g. System.exit();) when a message is received, and in your second application (when it is up) send a message to port XXX.
you also can implement a similar scenario using files. (1st application periodically checks a specific file exits and when it founds that file exists it terminates, 2nd application generates that specific file when it is up...

Comment: yes, that is what I was thinking to do just was curious if there was another way to do it without using ports etc. I did find a way to do it with using jps to kill the task if I want to go that way.  I will test a couple of different ways and decide which way I think will work best overall Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't the ant [Splash](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/splash.html) task do the trick?

> This task creates a splash screen. The splash screen is displayed for the duration of the build and includes a handy progress bar as well.

Comment: Interesting. I am not that ant fluent. so the splash would go away once ant was done but the application would still not be up and running since it takes a long time for the application to start up, we are working on this aspect as well,I will test this to see if there is a noticeable flicker on the splash screen hand off from ant to the jvm.  thanks for the thought and I will try it.

Comment: yes, that did not do what I was looking for. there is a noticeable flicker between the two splash screens.